# PayPal Payment Request Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the following code to integrate PayPal Payment System to my website and after the payment I am getting the following Notices and "Payment Failed" even when everything went smooth.

```
Notice: Undefined index: item_name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/payment/success.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: tx in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/payment/success.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: amount in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/payment/success.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: currency_code in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/payment/success.php on line 5

Payment Failed
```

I am using the following code to create the payment button

```
<div class="btn">
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="20Percents (12 Credits)">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="credits" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://20percents.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/logo-1.png">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/payment/cancel.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/payment/success.php">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And, the following code to verify the payment:

```
<?php
$item_name          = $_GET['item_name']; // I also tried $_REQUEST['item_name']; instead
$item_transaction   = $_GET['tx']; // Paypal transaction ID
$item_price         = $_GET['amount']; // Paypal received amount
$item_currency      = $_GET['currency_code']; // Paypal received currency type

$price = '10.00';
$currency='USD';

//Rechecking the product price and currency details
if($item_price==$price && $item_currency==$currency)
{
    $content = "<h1>Welcome, Guest</h1>";
    $content .= "<h1>Payment Successful</h1>";
}
else
{
    $content = "<h1>Payment Failed</h1>";
}
?>
```

I don't know why I am receiving these notices, any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method you gave in form is `POST`. But getting values using `$_GET[]`.
Change form to

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url ?>" method="get" name="frmPayPal1">
```

or change

```
$item_name = $_GET['item_name'];
```

to

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
```

Comment: what you have changed?

Comment: Tried both, tried changing method to get used the get function, didn't work and tried the post method and tried to use the $_post['item_name'] that too didn't work. Same problems

Comment: `$_POST['item_name'];`

Comment: I tried this and worked fine for me. Only issue was `tx` is not defined, which is not there in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to configure your account for PDT:

Log in to your PayPal account.
Click the Profile subtab.
Click Website Payment Preferences in the Seller Preferences column.
Under Auto Return for Website Payments, click the On radio button.
For the Return URL, enter the URL on your site that will receive the transaction ID posted by PayPal after a customer payment.
Under Payment Data Transfer, click the On radio button.
Click Save.
Click Website Payment Preferences in the Seller Preferences column.
Scroll down to the Payment Data Transfer section of the page to view your PDT identity token.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but these parameters worked for me with `$_POST` method. I added them to my ipn.php file

```
$item_transaction   = $_POST['txn_id'];
$item_price         = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$item_currency      = $_POST['mc_currency'];
```